# Compute the set of vertices of a polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the following polytope
$$ \Xi = \{ (\vec{a}_1\cdot \vec{x}+b_1, \cdots, \vec{a}_m \cdot \vec{x}+b_m)\mid C\vec{x}\leq d\}$$
how do I compute the set of vertices of $\Xi$?

Comment: What does $Cx\leq d$ mean for a vector $x$?

Comment: I'm guessing $C$ is a matrix and $d$ is a vector? If that's the case, it feels like your polytope is going to be strongly related to the one coming from the inequality. But more context would certainly help.

Answer (score 3):

You want to convert between the H-representation of a polytope and its V-representation. This is not easy but it is heavily studied,
and can now be accomplished with a variety of software packages.

- For example, there is a discussion of how to do this with *polymake* in
  [this discussion](http://forum.polymake.org/viewtopic.php?t=24).
- It can also be achieved with the [MPT3 software](http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/3/Geometry/OperationsWithPolyhedra).
- Underlying many of these packages is [Fukuda's cdd program](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/lrslib.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Note that $\{\vec{x}\mid C\vec{x}\leq d\}$ would be the standard H-rep to V-rep transformation. However, here we have the "affine mapping" specified by $\vec{a}$'s and $\vec{b}$'s. Does this cause problems?

Comment: @maomao: Ah, I didn't notice that. Not certain now... Perhaps work out a small (2D?) example to see the relationship between $C x \le d$ and the your polytope for various $a$ and $b$.